# How to add existing attribute to an attribute set programmatically in Magento 2

Tags: attributes, magento2, custom-attributes

How can I add some existing attributes to a new attribute set programmatically in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

in magento 2, there is color & manufactor attribute already created, but by defaultly this two attribute is not assigned to default attribute set. so, we can do like this. then it will assign this two attribute to default attribute when module installing.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    private $categorySetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, \Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }
    
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        try {
            /**
             * @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup
             */
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            /**
             * @var \Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetup
             */
            $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            
            $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
            $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId); // get default attribute set id 
            $attrGroupId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId); // get default attribute group id (in my case, it returns id of 'Product Details' group)

            $colorAttr = $eavSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'color');
            if($colorAttr) {
                $eavSetup->addAttributeToGroup(
                    $entityTypeId, 
                    $attributeSetId, 
                    $attrGroupId, 
                    'color', 
                    null
                );
            }

            $manufacturerAttr = $eavSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'manufacturer');
            if($manufacturerAttr) {
                $eavSetup->addAttributeToGroup(
                    $entityTypeId, 
                    $attributeSetId, 
                    $attrGroupId, 
                    'manufacturer', 
                    null
                );
            }

        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return;
        }
    }
```